# bundling with jspm in one single file

Tags: typescript, jspm

I have a problem with bundling my script with jspm. I have version 0.16.30 of jspm install both as dev dependency and global.

When i try to bundle I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

Here's the top of my config.js (I excluded maps etc.):

```
baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  typescriptOptions: {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  paths: {
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "main": "main",
      "defaultExtension": "ts"
    }
  },
```

And I bundle with following command:

```
jspm bundle-sfx app/main .\public\app.js
```

Which seems to go fine:

```
     Building the single-file sfx bundle for app/main...
ok   Built into public\app.js with source maps, unminified.
```

Here's how I set it all up in index.html:

```
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import("app");
    </script>
</body>
```

Any help is really be appreciated :)

Comment: How are you importing your scripts in your `.html` page?  Are you referencing the `jspm_packages/system.js` library before you make your `System.import()` call?

Comment: yes I call system.js before. I have updated my question to illustrate this.

Comment: Are you certain that you are not encountering a 404 error for jspm_packages/system.js when loading index.html?  According to the order of your scripts System should already be defined.

Comment: @ebpa your right! I've posted a wrong html I still have the issue though, but it seems not to be a problem. My javascripts loads fine anyway?